# How does WSARecv make use of lpOverlapped? How can I manually signal the event?

Tags: c++, winsock

I need to figure out how WSARecv uses the lpOverlapped argument when lpCompletionRoutine is null. It signals the event located in lpOverlapped, right? But there must be more to it than that.

I'm intercepting normal WSARecv calls so I can log packets, and I can capture the data just fine, but the client hangs and waits to be told that the recv operation is finished. I simply don't know exactly what the real WSARecv function does with lpOverlapped to notify the client that the operation is complete.

When lpOverlapped is passed into WSARecv, lpOverlapped->hEvent is null. So I can't simply do SetEvent() or WSASetEvent(). I can create an event by doing something like lpOverlapped->hEvent = WSACreateEvent() and then set the event, the client still doesn't seem to acknowledge it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

edit: Example of what I'm doing for my WSARecv call

```
    int proxyWSARecv(int unused, SOCKET s, LPWSABUF recvBuffer, DWORD bufferCount, LPDWORD bytesRecvd, LPDWORD flags,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine){


    WSAOVERLAPPED wsaoverlapped;
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED ourOverlapped = &wsaoverlapped;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int rc = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    int retnVal;

    __asm{
        push lpCompletionRoutine
        push ourOverlapped // our replacement lpoverlapped
        push flags
        push bytesRecvd
        push bufferCount
        push recvBuffer
        push s
        call p_WSARecv // real WSARecv
        mov retnVal, EAX
    }

    // get overlapped results and log packets here. etc
}
```

Comment: Could the client possibly be using [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Well, I'm using all of the same variables that the client is using with the exception of lpOverlapped. Wouldn't the client still proceed in that case? (I'll update my main post to show an example of what I'm doing)

Comment: If the client is using I/O completion ports, they are probably using [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and may be keying their own handling based on the returned `lpOverlapped` value, rather than only using the completion key. in that case, overriding `lpOverlapped` will cause this to fail. what you could do is save the caller's lpOverlapped struct, and overwrite it with your own contents to preserve the address. (If I'm not entirely off mark here, I'll probably post this as an answer)

Comment: Ok, well is there a way I can trigger the GetQueuedCompletionStatus stuff myself? The main thing is I need to copy the entire packet (to log it) before the game decrypts the packet itself. If I use the lpOverlapped provided, often times the packet will already have changed in memory by the time I get a look at it. I really appreciate your comments btw.

Comment: Why are you calling WSAStartup from your proxy routine? Shouldn't the host application do this for you, possibly expecting a different version?

Comment: I called it so I could create my own lpOverlapped. If I use their lpOverlapped for the legit WSARecv call, sometimes the client will alter the packet in the memory before I have a chance to copt it.

Comment: What? WSAStartup does not create overlapped completion structures...

Comment: Ok thanks, so I guess I don't need that. But that doesn't really change my problem does it?

Comment: You should really use a function pointer instead of the non bit and compiler portable asm

Comment: @Richard: You could trigger it using [`PostQueuedCompletionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but you need to use the same `dwCompletionKey` value as was given for `CompletionKey` when [`CreateIoCompletionPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was called. in which case you don't need to overwrite the original `OVERLAPPED` structure, just keep its address around.

Comment: @Hasturkun Thank you very much for the advice. That's pretty much what I'm looking for, although I haven't been able to successfully use PostQueuedCompletionStatus yet. I'm guessing the client called CreateIoCompletionPort before it called my proxy WSARecv function, so how am I to know what the dwCompletionKey is? Also, will the HANDLE CompletionPort just be the socket? Thanks!

Comment: @RichardM.: There's a simpler way to go about all this, namely, keep track of the user's `OVERLAPPED` structs, hook `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` and do your magic there. That way you are informed before the client is, and can copy out the data or similar. (do tell me if this is the case, and I will write a proper answer summarizing all this)

Comment: @Hasturkun I do believe that would work, however, what I'm doing is making a ws2_32.dll that I place in the folder of the client I want to sniff. I'd like to be able to do everything by only intercepting ws2_32 calls if at all possible.

Comment: @Hasturkun I broke down and decided to hook kernel32. I only hook the CreateIoCompletionPort function and I store the completionKey used and the HANDLE of existingCompletionPort. After I get the data I need, I call PostQueuedCompletionStatus with the values I stored. Although I was hoping not to have to hook kernel32, it does work! Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create (and later close) the event manually when setting up the overlapped structure. The event is set by the OS - you only have to wait for it or check it.

If the event of the overlapped structure is NULL, you can still wait for the socket events by using the socket itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. So the client might be hanging because it just monitors the socket events itself? Hmm wait that can't be it though. I can create my own lpOverlapped and use it just fine, the problem is then the client that uses my WSARecv call doesn't know when the recv is finished. Also, shouldn't the lpOverlapped be already set up since the client passes it to WSARecv (I'm trying to log packets in a video game)